# Is it required to close a connection in Web SQL?

Tags: sql, web-sql

Is it required to close a connection in Web SQL?  I am unable to access the DB a second time when I run the same code.  I am able to run and retrieve the data first time.  Please share the code if closing the connection in Web SQL is required.

Answer (score -4):

What is the purpose of not wanting to close the connection? Normally all connections should be closed to free resources, speed up processes and avoid locking situations. While most systems do garbage collection at a certain point of time, it is just waste of time and resources not to close when you know it is no longer needed.

Comment: I know that not closing DB connection will create problem. But DB close statements are not there in Web sql. That only i want

Comment: Then what is your question? First you ask whether it is a good idea to close connection, then you say that it is not possible? Can you please clarify your problem?

Comment: I am not sure if your problem still persist, but if it does, please clarify your needs. If the problem is solved, please post the solution here and close the issue. Or simply close the issue as unsolved if you are no longer interested in the solution.

Comment: I am sorry to say that your question is not clear at all and making a rude response does not clarify it. However, if your problem is solved, then please post the solution here. If you do not want to share the solution, then your question should be deleted. In either case, this should not be in status open.